# how to expand an array based on user input in c

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, function-definition

Im trying to write a program that asks the user for the size of an array and if they are asked again then the size of the array would increase based on the number they input.

```
int main()
{
   int size;
   int n;
   printf("Size of array: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   int *ptr = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   size = n;
   int n1;  
   do {
       printf("Input the increase size of the array: ");
       scanf("%d", &n1);
       size += n1;
       int *ptr = realloc((size)*sizeof(int));
   } while (n1 != -1);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is what I have got but how can I move this into a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters this call of the function realloc

```
int *ptr = realloc((size)*sizeof(int));
```

is incorrect. The function expects two arguments.

If you want to write a function that changes the size of a dynamically allocated  array then it can look the following way

```
int resize( int **a, size_t n )
{
    int *tmp = realloc( *a, n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( tmp != NULL ) *a = tmp;

    return tmp != NULL;
}
```

and the function can be called for example like

```
do {
    n1 = -1;
    printf("Input the increase size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
} while ( n1 != -1 && resize( &ptr, size += n1 ) );
```

Comment: Upvoted for not using `size - 1` with `realloc` when `-1` is entered.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( scanf( "%d", &n1 ) == 1 )
{
  int *tmp = realloc( ptr, (size + n1) * sizeof *ptr );
  if ( tmp )
  {
    ptr = tmp;
    size += n1;
  }
}
```

If `realloc` cannot satisfy the request it will return `NULL` and leave the original buffer in place; if you assign the result back to `ptr`, you run the risk of losing your only reference to that memory.  Therefore it's better to assign the result to a temporary pointer value and make sure it isn't `NULL` before updating `ptr`.

Also, you don't want to update your size until you know the `realloc` succeeded.

To put it into a function:

```
bool resize( int **ptr, int *size )
{
  int n1;
  bool success = false;

  printf( "Increase the size by: " );
  if ( scanf( "%d", &n1 ) == 1 )
  {
    int *tmp = realloc( *ptr, (*size + n1) * sizeof **ptr );
    if ( tmp )
    {
      *ptr = tmp;
      *size += n1;
      success = true;
    }
    else
    {
      fputs( "realloc could not extend the buffer\n", stderr );
    }
  }
  else
  {
    fputs( "Error or bad value on input\n", stderr );
  }
  return success;
}
```

and you would call it as

```
int main( void )
{
  int size = 0;
  int *ptr = NULL;
  ...
  if ( resize( &ptr, &size ) )
    // do stuff with ptr
  else
    // handle resize error
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to move the memory allocation into a function, you could do something like this:

```
int *allocate_array(int *ptr,size_t siz)
{
    return realloc(ptr,size * sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
    int n, n1, size, *ptr = NULL;

    printf("Size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ptr = allocate_array(ptr,n);
    size = n;
    do {
        printf("Input the increase in the array size: ");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        size += n1;
        ptr = allocate_array(ptr,size);
    } while (n1 > 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that your call to `realloc` was incorrect, as the first argument must be a pointer to the existing array. Also, you created a new `ptr` whose scope was just the while loop, which then ceased to exist outsid the loop.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to include corresponding headers to use the standard library.
- You have to pass the old pointer to reallocate to `realloc()`.
- You have to give another name to the pointer variable to get the return value of `realloc()` not to shadow (hide) the variable to store the pointer to the array.
- You should check the return values of `malloc()` and `realloc()` (and `scanf()` to check if they succeeded.
- Casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Fixed code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int size;
   int n;
   printf("Size of array: ");
   if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) return 1;
   int *ptr = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   if (ptr == NULL) return 1;
   size = n;
   int n1;  
   do {
       printf("Input the increase size of the array: ");
       if (scanf("%d", &n1) != 1) return 1;
       size += n1;
       int *new_ptr = realloc(ptr, (size)*sizeof(int));
       if (new_ptr == NULL) return 1;
       ptr = new_ptr;
   } while (n1 != -1);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the realloc function for allocate the mamory again.

void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);